# How to connect Weblate to Codeberg?

Tags: git, translation, weblate

Codeberg has a [service](https://translate.codeberg.org) for translating the software it hosts.  I tried to use it, but couldn't get it to work, despite a lot of searching in Weblate's menus and the web.  I always get "Gitea: User permission denied for writing".

I have set the repository push URL to git@…, since it seems to me that you're supposed to do it with SSH.  From what I gathered I have to add this Weblate instance's [SSH key](https://translate.codeberg.org/keys/) to my Codeberg account/my project, but if I try this in the [SSH / GPG Keys](https://codeberg.org/user/settings/keys) menu I get an "This SSH key has already been added to the server." error.

A lot of other people figured it out, so it can't be too hard, but I still can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after no one responded for quite some time here, I tried to see whether there is a other place to ask this question.  It turns out there is: [the official forum](https://codeberg.org/Codeberg/Community/issues).  There I quickly got the answer:  I have to add the "translate" user as a collaborator.

Thanks to [Otto/fnetX](https://codeberg.org/fnetX) for helping me!